# Can't catch Azelf?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Ok, so I tried to go catch Azelf yesterday. I live in a place with EST so it was around 5pm I went to catch him. I click on the hoopa ring and It just gives me a quote and nothing else. Then I try again later that night around 2 am in the morning and it does the same thing? I don't why. I know the requirements is to have 3 pokemon with max friendship and you come at certain times but even then, I can't start the battle. I already have Mespirit and Uxie, but I can't access Azelf. Help?

Comment: It's important you respect the timespan between 21:00 and 03:59. Have you tried beating Elite 4 again? It makes Legendary Pokemon to respawn.

Answer (score -1):

You can encounter it between 21:00 and 3:59. You should use a Quick ball or Master ball - I caught it with a master ball.